# Topological charge of angle field

Tags: computational-physics, topological-defects

I want to numerically calculate the topological charge using a 2D angle field defined on a rectangular grid. At each vertex of the grid, a value of angle is defined. Now, I want to calculate the topological charge by traversing a closed path over the grid. Such charges are quantized ($0, 2\pi, -2\pi, \cdots\cdots)$.

A method to calculate the charge is using the line integral over the closed path using the gradient of angle. I don't understand, how to evaluate such numerical integral using a gradient of angle.

[image: line integral]

[image]

For example, I want to calculate the topological charge enclosed by each smallest square by traversing the closed square path.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to take the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value) after you computed the differences for the gradient. Then you add up these principal values for the contour integration.

Comment: So, if theta1, theta2, theta3 and theta4 are the values of angles defined on the four consecutive vertices of a square (square loop: start->right->up->left->down) then the topological charge should be [cos(theta2-theta1)+sin(theta3-theta2)-cos(theta4-theta3)-sin(theta1-theta4)]/2pi?

Comment: No, the principal values are not the trigonometric function values.  See the link in my answer.